# is X-UA-Compatible the answer for IE browser compatibility?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, compatibility, x-ua-compatible

As in

Can we all stop searching and stop using css hacks and sorts? And is there a downside to using this tag?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as will all things web is: It depends

The `X-UA-Compatible` is really there for people that don't want to redo their website without hacks or are using functionality that is deprecated or removed in later versions (ex: DirectX filters are removed in IE10 but can be used in IE9 mode). Someone using best practices will have a proper doctype and will set `X-UA-Compatible='IE=edge'` this means that they are are not using any hacks for the latest version of IE and always want IE to render in the latest document mode. Ideally this means they are intending the same CSS/HTML/ECMAScript for all browsers.

The reality however as we're all aware is that IE8 still at the time I write this controls roughly a quarter of all desktops. Personally I code for the latest and just make it functional on anything older. I don't expect IE8 to be pretty, just to work.